# Cant install PHP yaml extension on Mac Big Sur

Tags: php, c, macos, yaml, homebrew

Running `pecl install yaml` errors out with `configure: error: ‘yaml.h’ header not found`

I have PHP 7.4.14 installed via Homebrew `brew install php@7.4`
along with libyaml `brew install libyaml` but still see this same error.

I also tried reinstalling xcode dev tools, as well as running pecl with sudo and all still the same error every time. Full output from pecl below.

```
Starting to download yaml-2.2.1.tgz (40,977 bytes)
............done: 40,977 bytes
8 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
Please provide the prefix of libyaml installation [autodetect] :
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-mattfergusonRvLour/yaml-2.2.1
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/yaml/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php-config --with-yaml
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.14
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.14/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.14/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.14/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.14/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.14/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.14/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.14/pecl/20190902
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.14/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable LibYAML suppot... yes, shared
checking for yaml headers... found in /usr/local
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... no
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... no
checking for stdint.h... no
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking yaml.h usability... no
checking yaml.h presence... no
checking for yaml.h... no
configure: error: ‘yaml.h’ header not found
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/yaml/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php-config --with-yaml’ failed
```

Comment: When prompted `Please provide the prefix of libyaml installation`, try entering `/usr/local`.

Comment: Got the same thing :/

Comment: It is certainly strange that the output says `checking for yaml headers... found in /usr/local` and afterwards `checking yaml.h presence... no`. You should probably file a bug with the maintainer of the package.

Answer (score 24):

maybe you should check this.

```
Please provide the prefix of libyaml installation [autodetect] :
```

today I  got the same thing.
I try input libyaml prefix solved.

here is the steps:

> step 1

```sh
$brew uninstall libyaml
Uninstalling /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.5... (10 files, 369.7KB)
```

> step 2

```sh
$brew install libyaml 
==> Downloading https://github.com/yaml/libyaml/archive/0.2.5.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/**/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/688fdcea5b88140cb83d1f72e3a77fa76b6560f0d66eabcea7d54cf9f06d5e72--libyaml-0.2.5.tar.gz
==> ./bootstrap
==> ./configure --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.5
==> make install
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.5: 10 files, 369.7KB, built in 12 seconds
```

> step3  **copy the prefix in step2.**

```sh
#In this case,It's
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.5
```

> step4

```sh
$sudo pecl install yaml
Password:
downloading yaml-2.2.1.tgz ...
Starting to download yaml-2.2.1.tgz (40,977 bytes)
............done: 40,977 bytes
8 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20160303
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
Please provide the prefix of libyaml installation [autodetect] :
```

> step5
> Paste the message you copied in step3, Press return.

```sh
Please provide the prefix of libyaml installation [autodetect] : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.5
```

at last.success.

Comment: You should add "extension=yaml.so" to php.ini, where is my php.ini in Big Sur?

Answer (score 2):

After installing libyaml with brew, copy the path to libyaml and paste it when pecl asks for prefix.
In my case, prefix was: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.5`

Answer (score 1):

ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/mcrypt/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php-config --with-mcrypt` failed.

Solution:

1.) mac install mcrypt:
`brew install mcrypt` or `pecl install mcrypt`

2.) mac install yaml:
`brew install libyaml` or `pecl install yaml`

Pro test is effective.